# is raphaeljs remove function causes the element to be falsey?

Tags: javascript, raphael

I have a check to see if the element has been drawn already by doing

```
if(element)
```

so I can choose whether to update the element or to draw it a new.

this works before the element is drawn, but not after element.remove()

even though if I use

```
alert(element);
```

I'm seeing undefined, which should be falsey.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: if element is a string (ie 'undefined'), this will return true. try doing an alert(typeof(element)) to see if it really is undefined, or a string representation of the word undefined.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for both cases, if element is falsy or if it is a string 'undefined' (as @Gwyn Howell mentioned in the comment):

```
if( !!element && element!=='undefined' )
```

Comment: shouldn't it be !element rather than double negation?

Comment: @FilipGórny no, The purpose of `!!` is 'casting' to boolean, not negation which is single `!`

Comment: @Tom Was the 'undefined' string the case? Or was there an other problem in your code?